# Conditional Count of changes over time?

Tags: r, conditional-operator

I´d like to count the number of changes of binary factor variable. This variable can change from time to time back and forth multiple times for every user id. Now I´d like to count he number of changes per user id to this variable over a given timespan.

The data is sorted by id,year,month,myfactor. I tried this in MySQL but had no success so far. 
Is there an easy way to do it in R? I though about adding another column to my data.frame and adding up conditions step by step... Maybe some %in% stuff ?

Thx in advance for suggestions...

Hmm, of course... here´s some example – sorry for not providing it immediately, my head hurts ;):

---

```
   myf   Year    month userid   
  1 A    2005       1    260           
  2 B    2005       2    260           
  3 B    2005       4    260           
  4 A    2005       5    260           
  5 B    2005       6    260           
  6 B    2005       1    261
```

if this is my dataset, I want to update the changes column, counting the number of changes of myf per user. Basically id like to end up with:

```
  user  changes
   260     3
   260     0
```

and so forth...

HTH

Comment: Could we have an example please?  Or at least some example data...

Comment: +1 for being so right...

Comment: Shouldn't be 3 and 0 in your example? Cause user 261 doesn't change. And it implies that A-B and A-A means 1 change.

Comment: yep Marek, you are right. edited it and will soon call it day. thx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
#Some data
dfr <- data.frame(
   binary_variable = runif(100) < .7,
   id = sample(7, 100, replace = TRUE)
)

#Split by id
split_by_id <- with(dfr, split(binary_variable, id))

#Number of changes
sapply(split_by_id, function(x) sum(diff(x) != 0))
```

Comment: This is pretty damn close to what I need. Right now I need to convert myf to some real TRUE / FALSE variable. With Richie Cotton data everything works fine. With my own I just get : Error in r[i1] - r[-length(r):-(length(r) - lag + 1L)] : 
  non-numeric argument to binary operator ... but probably I´ll figure that out..

Comment: To convert your 2-level `factor` to be a `logical` variable, try `myf == "A"`

Comment: @ran2 For factors use `as.numeric` or `unclass`. E.g. `split_by_id <- split(unclass(factor_variable), id))`.

Comment: That worked perfectly. after I solved my troubles with logical values, converting it to a logical variable was the solution. Should I use merge to add the newly obtained information to my dataset ? Or can I simply cbind it, because the sorting is not affected?

Comment: @ran2: you need to merge by `userid` (see my answer)

Comment: If that is really all you need, this is easily done with a oneliner :Data$extra <- ave(as.integer(Data$myf),Data$id,FUN=function(x) sum(diff(x)!=0))

Comment: Hell, with the help of Richie Cotton I solved it within 2 lines. Now, it´s even possible in one line. Thx a bunch, unfortunately I do not have enough accepts for y´all! a couple of hours ago I did not have any clue how to solve this and was desperately SQLing around.Yet I do not really get what´s being averaged (see help) with this ave function...

Answer (score 5):

Another edit :

Given your responses on the other solutions, you could get what you want in one line:

```
Data$extra <- ave(as.integer(Data$myf),Data$id,FUN=function(x) sum(diff(x)!=0))
```

No merge needed in this case.

---

"Over a given timespan" means that you could select a timespan and then apply the function. Joshuas answer is the fastest way around. There's a more general function that gives you more information on run lengths and values, `rle`. Be sure to check that one out.

Based on Joshuas answer, this example shows you how you can easily work with the dates to select a given timespan.

Edit: I updated the answer to show you how to easily convert your columns year and month into a date. You should also use `as.numeric` when applying the whole thing on a factor like yours.

```
#Testdata
set.seed(21)
Data <- data.frame(id=rep(letters[1:3],each=24),
                   year= rep(rep(c(2005,2006),each=12),6),
                   month=rep(1:12,6),
                   myf=sample(c("A","B"),24*3,TRUE))

#transformation
Data$dates <- as.Date(paste(Data$year,Data$month,"1",sep="-"))
#function

cond.count <- function(from,to,data){
    x <- data[data$dates>from & data$dates<to,]
    tapply(as.numeric(x$myf),x$id,function(y)sum(diff(y)!=0))
}

#example
from <- as.Date("2005-01-01")
to <- as.Date("2006-04-15")

cond.count(from,to,Data)
```

Comment: The `yearmon` class in `zoo` is handy when you only need monthly granularity.

Comment: @Joshua: very true. I normally use the Date class as I only use other packages reluctantly, given the trouble they can give. But it would be a nicer solution in this case.

Comment: How do I so consistently overlook `ave`?  Awesome solution!

Answer (score 2):

Here's my guess.

```
set.seed(21)
Data <- data.frame(id=sample(letters[1:3],20,TRUE),
                   date=sample(1:3,20,TRUE),
                   myfactor=sample(0:1,20,TRUE))
Data <- Data[order(Data$id,Data$date),]

DataCh <- aggregate(Data[,"myfactor",FALSE],
            by=Data[,c("id","date")], function(x) sum(diff(x)!=0))
DataCh <- DataCh[order(DataCh$id,DataCh$date),]
```

EDIT: Here's an update with your example data.

```
lines <- "   myf   Year    month userid   
 1 A    2005       1    260           
 2 B    2005       2    260           
 3 B    2005       4    260           
 4 A    2005       5    260           
 5 B    2005       6    260           
 6 B    2005       1    261 "

Data <- read.table(con <- textConnection(lines)); close(con)

DataCh <- aggregate(Data[,"myf",FALSE],
            by=Data[,"userid",FALSE], function(x) sum(diff(unclass(x))!=0))

merge(Data,DataCh,by="userid",suffixes=c("",".change"))
#   userid myf Year month myf.change
# 1    260   A 2005     1          3
# 2    260   B 2005     2          3
# 3    260   B 2005     4          3
# 4    260   A 2005     5          3
# 5    260   B 2005     6          3
# 6    261   B 2005     1          0
```